# Firestore security rules request.auth is always null

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I am unsuccessfully trying to tighten Firestore security with *custom claims*.

versions:

- Firebase: ^9.6.9
- Node: 16.14.0
- Next: 11.1.0

I have verified that my custom claims are set as they work as expected for certain collections/requests, specifically ones coming from NextJs Server Side Rendered functions.

I have tried:

- Refactoring every service to Firebase V9 instead of using compat.
- Changing the firestore rules in production
- setting up emulators (Note* I'm not using auth emulator)
- adding debug() to security rules
- signing out and back in again
- `request.auth.token` (which is what the debug shows on other reqs)
- as well as `request.resource.auth.token` as per [These Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#allowing_read_access_only_for_specific_fields) (incorrect usage)

From the security rules debug - `request.auth` is `null`

[image: debug-rules]

##### Update:

I see from the rules usage on the firebase console that the rules were treated as **errors** and **not denies**.

I have found strange behavior.

I am successfully able to use custom claims for any collection other than 'blog'.

**Successful rule matching tags:**

[image: successful]

I'm starting to think it has something to do with **NextJs Server Side Rendering** using `getServerSideProps()`

My code to retrieve blog entries:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const posts: BlogPost[] | any = await GetBlogPosts();
  return {
    props: {posts}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

interface extendedBlogPosts extends BlogPost {
  ['key']: string;
  id: string;
}
interface BlogPageProps {
  posts: extendedBlogPosts[];
  userProps: {user: UserInfo; userData: UserData};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the code in `getServerSideProps` runs in a trusted environment and accesses Firestore using an [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). If that is the case then the behavior you are seeing is expected, as the Admin SDKs access the database with elevated/administrative privileges and not as a specific user, and bypass all security rules.

---

Even if you're not using the Admin SDK, if that code runs in the server using the regular JavaScript SDK (or the one for Node.js, but not for administrative usage), your code is executing in a different environment than where the user signed in. So unless you've signed the user into the server-side code too, it will run without a signed in user, and thus the `request.auth` variable in your rules will be `null`.

Comment: Although very useful, I do however question if it is using the admin SDK. I believe the Admin SDK would bypass security rules and allow for any read or write operations as  opposed to resulting in errors or denies. I also have not imported the Admin SDK anywhere in my code other than Firebase Cloud Functions. `getServerSideProps` is a NextJs reserved function name which pre-loads data and injects props into components (For SEO purposes). The function is using `firebase.Firestore` queries as all of the other database functions are, but seemingly without passing the `firebase.User` object.

Comment: I added some more info on what could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

The current user information is stored in `request.auth`, not in `request.resource.auth` as you are using in your first and last screenshots.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have tried using request.auth.token. The screenshot of my emulator debug section shows that request.auth is null when I have rules (regardless of whether I’ve used request.auth != null or other) and it exists with tokens when I don’t. I also believe this should be updated on the documentation.

Comment: It's hard to help troubleshoot a moving target like this. In 2 of the 3 screenshots you had when I answered you're using `request.resource.auth`, which won't work unless you have added an `auth` field to the relevant documents yourself. --- I recommend taking a (renewed) look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it's most likely we can help if we see the one approach you think should work, rather than everything you've tried.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for the suggestion. I have streamlined the question to include only the approach I believe should work. I have also found new information regarding which kinds of requests are resulting in errors. Database functions ran traditionally in NextJs components work as expected in security rules. Functions that are server side rendered do not.

Comment: It sounds like those non-working functions are using the Admin SDK to access Firestore. I'll write up a new answer for that